# r - Constructing a row index based on arrays of starting point and length

Tags: arrays, r, indexing

the best is to show my problem with an example. I want an efficient code (not a for loop since thats easy).

Lets say I have a 3x2 matrix as follows:

```
idx = array( c(4, 12, 7,
               2, 3,  2), c(3,2))
```

I want a new vector of indexes that follows this logic:

- The first column of idx matrix points to a starting point of an index
- The second column of idx matrix shows the length of incremental indices

So the new vector that I am trying to generate will look like:

```
newVector = c(4,5,12,13,14,7,8)
```

so you can see that it has (4,5),(12,13,14),(7,8), which are based upon the idx matrix.

How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: I think you have your data messed up. `2` comes after `4` in the same column in your data and `3`, `7` and `2` are all in the same column too. This should probably bee `idx <- matrix(c(4, 2, 12, 3, 7, 2), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)`. And where did that `9` came out from in your expected output? Either way, one way could be ```unlist(mapply(`:`, idx[, 1], idx[, 1] + idx[, 2] - 1))``` though it's still some type of a loop I guess.

Comment: Thanks, corrected the array initialization and the 9 was removed!

Comment: Your array is just a matrix, you know that right? Try `class(idx)`

Comment: I know that, by array I meant an R array.. your solution is awesome! It worked (even though its internally a loop).